# Effective degrees of freedom for a booster? Complexity of a booster?

Tags: boosting, degrees-of-freedom

I was asked recently (in a job interview) about the complexity of a booster, and I had a decent intuitive answer, but I'm unsure about how to formalize it.

Clearly it'll be a function of the complexity of the base learner, the learning rate, and the number of iterations.  But what specific function?

Say we're working with a tree with a depth of $D$.  That means that there should be $2^D$ degrees of freedom for that tree.  The complexity of that tree within the algorithm is going to be proportional to the learning rate.  But what's the specific function?  Is it just multiplicative:  $\lambda \times 2^D$?

Then, I know that boosting fits an additive model.  But is the complexity similarly additive?  Intuitively it seems like it should be, but I'm unsure of how to think about this formally, and my doubt stems from the adaptive nature of subsequent trees.

Lastly:  is there a 1:1 relationship between effective degrees of freedom and "complexity"?  Googling, I see measures of complexity that relate to the interactivity of components of the system.  This implies that complexity relates to the depth of the constituent trees, and to the shape of the subspaces defined by each tree.  But again, I'm unsure about how to think about this formally.

Comment: I guess we can always get the per learner estimates, formulate them into what a GAM would call "the smoother matrix" (i.e. the basis functions the GAM has estimated)  and then get the trace of that matrix say ($A(\lambda)$? $\lambda$ being a bandwidth) Effectively do what we would do for a GCV but instead of smoothing we use the individual learners. Good question by the way (+1) and I hope the interview went well! I am sure they wouldn't ask something like this if they were not already impressed with what you have told them up to that point!